# How can I allow multiple containers to see a host's network with Wireshark and allow them to remain seperately addressable

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, wireshark, ubuntu-18.04, esxi

I would like to have multiple `Ubuntu 18.04 server` VMs running on an `ESXi 6` server, running multiple containers, started with `docker-compose`, that:

1. Allow access to a remote desktop environment through `HTTP` (from a Chromebook)
2. Can run `Wireshark` on their main interface to capture traffic on the entire network
3. Can communicate with TCP/IP on the same VM, between containers, with discreet addresses, with same port used for the connection on both ends (relevant tool functions shown below, uses `python3.7`)
4. Can communicate with TCP/IP to different containers on different VMs, with discreet addresses, with the same port used for the connection on both ends

The network is set up with a central WAP that has Internet through the WAN, and connects to a server tower (running `ESXi`) via hard link. The `ESXi` server has two port groups, one connected to the NIC that has access to the WAP (`VM-Network`), the other connected to a dead NIC (`Exercise-Network`). All VMs are connected to the `Exercise-Network` after being initialized. There is a central DHCP server for the `Exercise-Network`, but no gateway.

I have solved problems 1 and 2 by using the `dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc:bionic-lxqt`container and running `docker-compose` with `network_mode: host` to allow `Wireshark` to see all traffic, but using the the host network makes it impossible to address specific containers.

I attempted to allow multiple containers to successfully share the same address space by changing the port the desktop is server from, but it doesn't allow communications and each container isn't directly "addressable"

**The python functions that implement the client/server portion of the `python3.7` tool I wrote that communicates between hosts (purposefully insecure!):**

```py
def startListener():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    server = websockets.serve(listener, "127.0.0.1", 9999)
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()

async def listener(websocket, path):
    msg = await websocket.recv()

    print('SSC>>>Received: ' + msg)
    reply = input('SSC>>>Reply: ')

    if reply is None or reply == '' or reply.isspace():
        await websocket.send(' ')
    else:
        await websocket.send(reply)

async def sendMessage(host):
    uri = "ws://" + str(host) + ":9999"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        msg = input('SSC>>>Message (' + str(host) + '): ')
        await websocket.send(user + '//' + msg)

        reply = await websocket.recv()
        print('SSC>>>Reply (' + str(host) + '): '+ reply)
        return
```

**Dockerfile:**
(I removed installation of the aforementioned tool, it's not important to this issue)

```
FROM dorowu/ubuntu-desktop-lxde-vnc:bionic-lxqt
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y \
        python3 \
        python3-pip \
        wireshark \
        nano

RUN sed -i "s/listen 80/listen 90/" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

(The sed command is used to change the port to connect to the desktop with, allowing multiple connections to different containers on the same VM. When docker-compose runs I just change the sed commend to replace port 80 with port x-- shown dockerfile allows connection to the VM for HTTP on port 90)

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

services:
  dt1:
    image: uwardlaw/omf:dt-1
    volumes:
      - ./shared:/home/sandbox/shared
    environment:
      - HTTP_PASSWORD=httptest1
      - USER=test1
      - PASSWORD=test1pass
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
```

(docker-compose cut down, there are roughly 7-8 'dts' per VM, but they all look the same-- current example runs one. Also, for speed, a seperate functions builds the image and pushes it to dockerhub, which is why the pulled image is tagged differently)